# some characters that need to use '\' before them to delete

Tags: python, regex

Which characters need '\' before them to delete from a text ?
Like this :

```
import re
my_source = re.sub('\(','',my_source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which characters need '\' before them to delete from a text ?

Characters you must and must not escape depends on the regular expression indication you're working with.

For the most part the following are characters that need escaped outside of character classes `[]` are:

```
.^$*+?()[{\|
```

And the characters `^-]\` need escaped inside character classes. It's not always needed to escape `-` inside character classes, but to me this is alot safer to do.

But note as I stated this does depend on the regex indication you are working with.

Examples using `re.sub()`

Replace the, `(` and `)` in the string..

```
oldStr = '(foo) bar (baz)'
print re.sub(r'[()]+', '', oldStr)
```

Output:

```
foo bar baz
```

Example using `re.search()`

We are using `re.search` to find the text between the first `(` and `)` in the string. We escape the `(` next use a regex capture group `([a-zA-Z]+)` looking for word characters, ending it with `)`

```
m = re.search('\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)', oldStr)
print m.group(1)  #prints 'foo'
```

Example using `re.findall()`

```
m = re.findall(r'\(([a-zA-Z]+)\)', oldStr)
print ", " . join(m)

# prints `foo, baz`
```

Answer (score 4):

Special characters (`.`, `?`, `(`, `)`, ...) should be escaped to match literally:

You can find special characters from [here - Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

But you don't need to do it yourself. You can use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape('(')
'\\('
>>> print(re.escape('('))
\(
```

Comment: i don't understand your example!   please explaine more.               what do 'escape' exactly do ?

Comment: @sasan, `re.escape` escape non-alphanumerics. By using it you can match arbitrary literal string.

Answer (score 2):

Since from your question it appears that you just want to delete certain characters from a string, you don't even need to use regex at all. The easiest way to do this in python is using the `replace` method of string objects:

```
>>> my_source = 'Hello, world!'
>>> my_source.replace(", world", "")
'Hello!'
```

If you have a list of strings to delete from your input, you can do it like this:

```
>>> my_source = 'ABCDEFG_HI(JKLM).NOP'
>>> deletions = ('_', '(', ')', 'EF', 'O')
>>> for deletion in deletions:
...     my_source = my_source.replace(deletion, "")
... 
>>> my_source
'ABCDGHIJKLM.NP'
```

Comment: Is there any different between 'replace' and 'sub' ?

Comment: Using `re.sub` parses the replacement pattern as a regular expression. If you don't know what regular expressions are, you definitely don't want to be using `re.sub`.